# Return a Radio Button Value in MeteorJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to follow this  [tutorial](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-a-meteor-template/) to implement a, in my case, radio button. I am iterating over the categories but in my case, Job Types:

**Views:**

```
  <label>Category</label>
  {{#each jobTypes}}
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input id="jobType_{{_id}}" type="radio" value="{{_id}}" name="jobType" {{hasJobType}} /> {{name}}
    </label>
  {{/each}}
```

**My Submit js:**

```
Template.jobCreate.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var job = {
      jobTitle: $(e.target).find('[name=jobTitle]').val(),
      aboutRole: $(e.target).find('[name=aboutRole]').val(),
      howToApply: $(e.target).find('[name=howToApply]').val(),
      aboutCandidate: $(e.target).find('[name=aboutCandidate]').val(),
      benefits: $(e.target).find('[name=benefits]').val(),

      // for the radio button. This feels wrong:
      jobTypes: $(e.target).find('input[name=jobType]:checked').val(),

    };

    Meteor.call('jobInsert', job, function(error, result) {
      // display the error to the user and abort
      if (error)
        return alert(error.reason);
      Router.go('jobPage', {_id: result._id});
    });
  }
});
```

**My helper js:**

```
Template.jobCreate.helpers({
  hasJobType: function() {
    return _.contains(job.jobTypes, this.name) ? 'checked' : '';
  }
});
```

If I echo return `{{jobTypes}}`, I get the radio button `_id` but if I replace value `{{_id}}` with `{{name}}`, in the views, I get the name but the tutorial uses the `id` instead. Am I missing something is my js?

I have yet to implement an edit/delete js.

Comment: What's the question? What is not working for you?

Comment: Hi @EliezerSteinbock, it works to be honest. I thought I was doing something wrong. I've replaced value _id with value name.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend using [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) instead of rolling your own form solution.